# Rails simple form how to wrap HTML around label and input element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

I started playing around with [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) and found a very good gem called [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). When simple form generates the input elements I tried to fiddle out how to wrap another HTML element around the `label` and `input` field.

```
= f.input :existingname, placeholder: 'Your name is?'
```

and the output is:

```
<div>
  <label></label>
  <input>
</div>
```

but I want to have:

```
<div>
  <span><label></label></span> 
  <span><input></span>
</div>
```

Any help with this?

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather from the site, you need to add a custom wrapper edit some settings in `config/initalizers/simple_form.rb`

That file also has several pre-existing settings you can edit to add wrappers.

One line that stood out was:

```
config.item_wrapper_tag = :span
```

I haven't had a chance to play with it, but there is plenty of documentation in the file. If they don't work out, you can create a custom wrapper, documentation for that can be found on the wiki at the simple_form github page [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers)